# Fast enumeration and adding objects to NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray, fast-enumeration

I am attempting to add objects to `NSMutableArray "allItems1"`

```
for (PMGWine *w in [[PMGWineStore sharedStore]allItems]) {

    [allItems1 addObject:w];

    NSLog(@"%@", w);

}

    NSLog(@"%d", [allItems1 count]);
```

`[[PMGWineStore sharedStore]allItems]` consists of 15 objects which print out perfectly in the first `NSLog` statement. But `[allItems1 count]` shows 0.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you allocated allItems1 ?

Comment: I declared an NSMutableArray *allItems1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you are not allocated the allItems1 array.

Please add this line before the for loop.

```
allItems1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Also you can use:

```
allItems1 = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[PMGWineStore sharedStore] allItems]] retain];
```

or

```
allItems1 = [[PMGWineStore sharedStore] allItems] copy];
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to initialize `allItems1` NSMutableArray.
Before the `for` you write

```
allItems1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

You could also have written:

```
allItems1 = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[PMGWineStore sharedStore]allItems]];
```

instead of the for cycle.